# wrapper class check not working on VF page to render a block

Tags: apex, visualforce

Below is my VF page on which i am trying to render a table using page block if the wrapper "productStyleWrapperList"is not empty. If.If it is empty i want to display a custom message.

I don't know why it's not working and i keep getting exception on my page instead of custom message i want to show.Error is "   Content Starts Here
List has no rows for assignment to SObject "Its because my wrapper class is empty.

Can someone please help me figure out what i am doing wrong

VF page

```
 <apex:page standardController="gii__SalesOrder__c" extensions="AddSalesOrderLinesCon" sidebar="true" tabStyle="gii__SalesOrder__c">
  <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SalesOrderQuoteWizardResource, 'css/core.css')}"/>


  <apex:sectionHeader title="{!$Label.AddLinesFromForecast}"  subTitle="{!gii__SalesOrder__c.Name}"/>


    <apex:form >

    <apex:pageBlock >
        <c:WizardChevron id="Wizard_Chevron" Total_positions="{!strTotalPositions}" 
            Default_Position="{!strDefaultHighlightPosition}" Highlight_position="{!strHighlightPosition}"
            Map_Position_Name="{!mapPositionAttributes}"/>

        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom" >
            <div class="flowButtonPanel">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!previousPage}" value="{!$Label.Previous_Button}"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!SaveProducts}" value="{!$Label.Next_buttton}"/>
                <apex:commandLink action="{!Cancel}"  value="{!$Label.Cancel_button}" styleClass="cancelBtnCss" />
            </div>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!$Label.Search_Title}" collapsible="false" >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="3">
                <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.Product_Name_Search}"></apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputText value="{!searchtext}" />
                <apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.Search_button}" action="{!getProducts}" reRender="productdata"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>


        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="{!$Label.TableTitle_Products_From_Forecast}" collapsible="true" id="productdata">
         <center>
            <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="pSearchShowMore" id="otpNav" >             
                <apex:image url="/img/search_prevarrow_disabled.gif" styleClass="prevArrow" rendered="{!NOT(Con.HasPrevious)}"/>
                <apex:image url="/img/search_prevarrow.gif" title="Previous Page" styleClass="prevArrow" rendered="{!Con.HasPrevious}"/>
                <apex:commandLink action="{!Previous}" title="Previous Page" value="Previous Page" rendered="{!HasPrevious}" reRender="productdata"/>
                <apex:outputPanel styleClass="pShowLess noLink" style="color:grey" rendered="{!NOT(HasPrevious)}">Previous Page</apex:outputPanel>         
                &nbsp;({!IF(PageNumber == 0,1,(PageNumber * PageSize)+1)}-{!IF(CountTotalRecords != null && CountTotalRecords < PageSize,CountTotalRecords,((PageNumber+1) * PageSize))})&nbsp;
                <apex:outputPanel styleClass="pShowLess noLink" style="color:grey" rendered="{!NOT(HasNext)}" >Next Page</apex:outputPanel>         
                <apex:commandLink title="Next Page" value="Next Page" rendered="{!HasNext}" action="{!Next}" reRender="productdata"/>&nbsp;
                <apex:image url="/img/search_nextarrow.gif" title="Next Page" styleClass="nextArrow" rendered="{!Con.HasNext}"/>
                <apex:image url="/img/search_nextarrow_disabled.gif" rendered="{!NOT(Con.HasNext)}"/>          
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </center>
        <br/>
        <apex:outputPanel >
        <table style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;" class="list" >
            <thead class="rich-table-thead">
                <tr style="width:100%;" class="headerRow">
                    <th class="headerRow" scope="col">{!$Label.Header_Product_Style}</th>
                    <th class="headerRow" scope="col">{!$Label.Header_Allocation_Quantity}</th>
                    <th class="headerRow" scope="col">{!$Label.Header_Product_Name}</th>
                    <th class="headerRow" scope="col">{!$Label.Header_Product_Code}</th>
                    <th class="headerRow" scope="col">{!$Label.Header_Forecast}</th>
                    <th class="headerRow" scope="col">{!$Label.Header_Available_In_Inventory}</th>
                    <th class="headerRow" scope="col">{!$Label.Header_Order_Quantity}</th>
                    <th class="headerRow" scope="col">{!$Label.Header_Unit_Price}</th>
                    <th class="headerRow" scope="col">{!$Label.Header_Unit_Amount_Off}</th>
                    <th class="headerRow" scope="col">{!$Label.Header_Discount_Percent}</th>
                    <th class="headerRow" scope="col">{!$Label.Header_Pricing_Overridden_Reason}</th>
                    <th class="headerRow" scope="col">{!$Label.Header_Selling_Unit_of_Measure}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <apex:repeat value="{!productStyleWrapperList}" var="prods">
                <tr class="dataRow">
                    <td class="acronymheader dataCell">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!prods.productStyle}"></apex:outputText>
                    </td>
                    <td class="acronymheader dataCell" align="right">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!productStyleQtyMap[prods.productStyleId]}"></apex:outputText>
                    </td>
                    <td class="acronymheader dataCell">
                    </td>
                    <td class="acronymheader dataCell">
                    </td>
                    <td class="acronymheader dataCell">
                    </td>
                    <td class="acronymheader dataCell">
                    </td>
                    <td class="acronymheader dataCell">
                    </td>
                    <td class="acronymheader dataCell">
                    </td>
                    <td class="acronymheader dataCell">
                    </td>
                    <td class="acronymheader dataCell">
                    </td>
                    <td class="acronymheader dataCell">
                    </td>
                    <td class="acronymheader dataCell">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <apex:repeat value="{!prods.productList}" var="prod">
                    <tr class="dataRow">
                        <td class="dataCell">
                        </td>
                        <td class="dataCell">
                        </td>
                        <td class="dataCell">
                            <apex:outputField value="{!Prod.sol.gii__Product__c}"></apex:outputField>
                        </td>
                        <td class="dataCell">
                            <apex:outputText value="{!Prod.ProductCode}"></apex:outputText>
                        </td>
                        <td class="dataCell" align="right">
                            <apex:outputText value="{!Prod.forecast}"></apex:outputText>
                        </td>
                        <td class="dataCell" align="right">
                            <apex:outputText value="{!ProductToAvailableMap[Prod.Id]}"></apex:outputText>
                        </td>
                        <td class="dataCell">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!Prod.sol.gii__OrderQuantity__c}"></apex:inputField>
                        </td>
                        <td class="dataCell">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!Prod.sol.gii__UnitPrice__c}"></apex:inputField>
                        </td>
                        <td class="dataCell">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!Prod.sol.gii__UnitAmountOff__c}"></apex:inputField>
                        </td>
                        <td class="dataCell">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!Prod.sol.gii__DiscountPercent__c}"></apex:inputField>
                        </td>
                        <td class="dataCell">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!Prod.sol.gii__PricingOverriddenReason__c}"></apex:inputField>
                        </td>
                        <td class="dataCell">
                            <apex:OutputText value="{!Prod.sellingUnitOfMeasure}"></apex:OutputText>                         
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:repeat>
        </table>
        </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Apex code

```
global class AddSalesOrderLinesCon{

    public ApexPages.StandardSetController con{get; set;}
    Public gii__SalesOrder__c salesOrder;
    Public gii__SalesOrder__c sorder{get;set;}
    Public Id warehouseId;
    public List<gii__Product2Add__c> products{get; set;}
    public Map<Id, Id> ProductToInventoryMap{get; set;}
    public Map<Id, Decimal> ProductToForecastMap{get; set;}
    public Map<Id, Decimal> ProductToAvailableMap{get; set;}
    public List<ProductStyleWarpper> productStyleWrapperList{get;set;}
    public list<gii__Location__c> location; 
    public Map<Id, List<gii__Product2Add__c>> styleToProductMap{get;set;}
    public Map<Id, String> productStyleNameMap{get;set;} 
    public Map<Id, Decimal> productStyleQtyMap{get;set;} 
    public Set<Id> productIds{get;set;}
    public Map<String, gii.ProductPrice.ProductRefPrice> mapPP{get;set;}
    // will be used to store search product name
    public string searchtext {get;set;}
    // will be used to display totol number of records
    public Integer CountTotalRecords{get;set;}
    // will be used to display number of pages
    public Integer NoOfPages{get;set;}
    // will be used to set page size
    public Integer PageSize{get;set;}
    // will be used to display page number
    public Integer PageNumber{get;set;}
    public String priceBookName{get;set;}

    // will store product ids
    private Set<Id> productRefIds{get;set;}

    public String strTotalPositions {get;set;}
    public String strDefaultHighlightPosition {get;set;}
    public String strHighlightPosition {get;set;}
    public map<Integer, map<String,String>> mapPositionAttributes {get; set;}    


    public AddSalesOrderLinesCon(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        // will use label for this
        PageSize = integer.valueOf(Label.Add_Lines_From_Forecast_Page_size);
        PageNumber = 0;
        searchtext = '';

        salesOrder = (gii__SalesOrder__c)controller.getRecord();

        strTotalPositions  = '3';
        strDefaultHighlightPosition = '1';
        strHighlightPosition = '2';
        mapPositionAttributes = new map<Integer, map<String,String>>();
        mapPositionAttributes = WizardChevronManager.fetchMapChevronParameters('Create_Sales_Order',strTotalPositions);

        sorder = [select gii__PriceBookName__c, gii__Warehouse__c, gii__Account__r.phone, gii__Account__r.owner.email, gii__Account__r.name, Sales_Year__c, Sales_Year__r.name, gii__Account__c, Name from gii__SalesOrder__c where id=: salesOrder.Id];
        priceBookName = sorder .gii__PriceBookName__c;

        system.debug('salesOrder:'+ salesOrder);
        warehouseId = sorder.gii__Warehouse__c;
        productRefIds = new Set<Id>();
        ProductToInventoryMap = new Map<Id,Id>();
        ProductToForecastMap = new Map<Id, Decimal>();
        ProductToAvailableMap = new Map<Id, Decimal>();

        location = [select Id from gii__Location__c where Sales_Year__c =: sorder.Sales_Year__c and gii__Warehouse__c= :warehouseId limit 1];

        for(Forecast__c forecast: [select Id, Product_Inventory__c, Product_Inventory__r.Available_to_Sell__c, Total_Quantity__c,Product_Reference__c, Warehouse__c from Forecast__c where Warehouse__c =: warehouseId order by Product_Reference__r.Name asc]){
            productRefIds.add(forecast.Product_Reference__c);
            ProductToForecastMap.put(forecast.Product_Reference__c, forecast.Total_Quantity__c);
            ProductToAvailableMap.put(forecast.Product_Reference__c, forecast.Product_Inventory__r.Available_to_Sell__c);
            ProductToInventoryMap.put(forecast.Product_Reference__c, forecast.Product_Inventory__c);
        }

        getProducts();

    }

    public PageReference previousPage(){
        PageReference pg = new PageReference('/apex/CreateSalesOrderHeader?id='+sorder.gii__Account__c+'&soid='+sorder.id);
        return pg;
    }

    /**********************************
        will navigate to sales order header mobile version page
        create on 7-May-2015
        Name        :   previous_PageMobile

    **********************************/
    public PageReference previous_PageMobile(){
        PageReference pg = new PageReference('/apex/CreateSalesOrderHeader_mobile?id='+sorder.gii__Account__c+'&soid='+sorder.id);
        return pg;
    }

    /**********************************
        will be used to get products created for paging purpose
        create on 13-april
        Name        :   getProducts
        productId   :   product ids     
    **********************************/
    public void getProducts()
    {
        system.debug('\n--searchtext--'+searchtext+'\n--'+string.isEmpty(searchtext));
        integer offset = PageNumber*PageSize;
        String soql4count = '';
        if(string.isEmpty(searchtext))
        {
            products = [select Id, gii__ProductStyle__c,gii__StockUM__c, gii__SellingUnitofMeasure__c, gii__SellingUnitofMeasure__r.Name ,gii__ProductStyle__r.Name, gii__ProductCode__c, Name from gii__Product2Add__c where Id in: productRefIds and gii__ProductStyle__c!=null order by gii__ProductStyle__r.Name limit :PageSize offset :offset ];
            soql4count = 'Select count() from gii__Product2Add__c where Id in :productRefIds and gii__ProductStyle__c!=null';
        }
        else
        {
            String search ='%'+searchtext+'%';
            products = [select Id, gii__ProductStyle__c,gii__StockUM__c, gii__SellingUnitofMeasure__c, gii__SellingUnitofMeasure__r.Name ,gii__ProductStyle__r.Name, gii__ProductCode__c, Name from gii__Product2Add__c where Id in: productRefIds and gii__ProductStyle__c!=null and Name like :search order by gii__ProductStyle__r.Name limit :PageSize offset :offset ];           
            soql4count = 'Select count() from gii__Product2Add__c where Id in :productRefIds and gii__ProductStyle__c!=null and Name like :search';
        }
        system.debug('\n--products--'+products);


        CountTotalRecords= Database.countQuery(soql4count);
        system.debug('\n--CountTotalRecords--'+CountTotalRecords);      
        if(Math.mod(CountTotalRecords, PageSize) == 0)
            NoOfPages = CountTotalRecords/PageSize;
        else
            NoOfPages = CountTotalRecords/PageSize + 1;

        styleToProductMap = new Map<Id, List<gii__Product2Add__c>>();
        productStyleNameMap = new Map<Id, String>();
        productIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(gii__Product2Add__c prod: products){
            productIds.add(prod.Id);
            if(styleToProductMap.get(prod.gii__ProductStyle__c) == null)
               styleToProductMap.put(prod.gii__ProductStyle__c, new List<gii__Product2Add__c>());
            styleToProductMap.get(prod.gii__ProductStyle__c).add(prod);
            productStyleNameMap.put(prod.gii__ProductStyle__c, prod.gii__ProductStyle__r.Name);
        }

        findProductUnitPrice();
        createProductWrapper();
        findAllocationQuanityForStyles();
    }

    public void findProductUnitPrice(){
        List<gii.ProductPrice.ProductRefPrice> pp = new List<gii.ProductPrice.ProductRefPrice> ();
        // Instantiate ProductRefPrice and assign inputs to the members of object
        for(Id prodId: productIds){
            gii.ProductPrice.ProductRefPrice p = new gii.ProductPrice.ProductRefPrice();
            p.ProductReferenceId = prodId;
            p.PriceBookName = priceBookName;
            p.Key = prodId;
            pp.add(p);
        }

        mapPP = new mAP<String, gii.ProductPrice.ProductRefPrice> ();
        mapPP = gii.ProductPrice.getProductUnitPrice(pp);
        system.debug('mapPP'+mapPP);
        system.debug('mapPP'+productIds);

    }

    public PageReference SaveProducts(){
        List<gii__SalesOrderLine__c> solToInsert = new List<gii__SalesOrderLine__c>();
        for(ProductStyleWarpper sylewrap: productStyleWrapperList){
            for(ProductLineWrapper prod: sylewrap.productList){
                gii__SalesOrderLine__c sol = prod.sol;
                if(sol.gii__OrderQuantity__c !=null){
                    solToInsert.add(sol);
                }
            }
        }

        system.debug('solToInsert: '+solToInsert);
        if(solToInsert.size()>0)
            insert solToInsert;
        PageReference returnPage = new PageReference('/apex/ApplyDiscount?id=' + salesOrder.Id); 
        return returnPage;
    }

    /**********************************
        will navigate to Discount mobile version page
        create on 7-May-2015
        Name        :   Save_ProductsMobile

    **********************************/
    public PageReference Save_ProductsMobile(){
        List<gii__SalesOrderLine__c> solToInsert = new List<gii__SalesOrderLine__c>();
        for(ProductStyleWarpper sylewrap: productStyleWrapperList){
            for(ProductLineWrapper prod: sylewrap.productList){
                gii__SalesOrderLine__c sol = prod.sol;
                if(sol.gii__OrderQuantity__c !=null){
                    solToInsert.add(sol);
                }
            }
        }

        system.debug('solToInsert: '+solToInsert);
        if(solToInsert.size()>0)
            insert solToInsert;
        PageReference returnPage = new PageReference('/apex/ApplyDiscount_mobile?id=' + salesOrder.Id); 
        return returnPage;
    }

    public void findAllocationQuanityForStyles(){
        productStyleQtyMap = new Map<Id, Decimal>();
        for(gii__ProductInventory__c pibl: [select Id, Available_To_Sell__c,gii__Product__c  from gii__ProductInventory__c where gii__Warehouse__c=: warehouseId and gii__Product__c in: productStyleNameMap.keySet()]){
             productStyleQtyMap.put(pibl.gii__Product__c, pibl.Available_To_Sell__c);       
        }
        for(Id styleId: productStyleNameMap.keySet()){
            if(productStyleQtyMap.get(styleId) == null)
                productStyleQtyMap.put(styleId, 0.0);       
        }

        /*for(Id prodId: productIds){
            if(productStyleQtyMap.get(prodId) == null)
                productStyleQtyMap.put(prodId, 0.0);       
        }*/

    }

    public void createProductWrapper(){
         productStyleWrapperList = new List<ProductStyleWarpper>();   
         for(Id styleId :styleToProductMap.keySet()){
             ProductStyleWarpper stylewrap = new ProductStyleWarpper();
             stylewrap.productStyle = productStyleNameMap.get(styleId);
             stylewrap.productStyleId = styleId;
             List<ProductLineWrapper> productswrap = new List<ProductLineWrapper>();
             for(gii__Product2Add__c prod: styleToProductMap.get(styleId)){
                ProductLineWrapper prodWrapper = new ProductLineWrapper();
                prodWrapper.Name = prod.Name;
                prodWrapper.Id = prod.Id;
                prodWrapper.ProductCode = prod.gii__ProductCode__c;
                if(prod.gii__SellingUnitofMeasure__c != null)
                    prodWrapper.sellingUnitOfMeasure = prod.gii__SellingUnitofMeasure__r.Name;
                else
                    prodWrapper.sellingUnitOfMeasure = prod.gii__StockUM__c;
                prodWrapper.forecast = ProductToForecastMap.get(prod.Id);
                prodWrapper.AvailableInInventory = ProductToAvailableMap.get(prod.Id);

                gii__SalesOrderLine__c sol = new gii__SalesOrderLine__c();
                sol.gii__Warehouse__c = warehouseId;
                sol.gii__Product__c  = prod.Id;
                sol.gii__SalesOrder__c = salesOrder.Id;
                sol.gii__UnitPrice__c = mapPP.get(prod.Id).UnitPrice;
                prodWrapper.sol = sol;

                productswrap.add(prodWrapper);

             }
             productswrap.sort();
             stylewrap.productList = productswrap;
             productStyleWrapperList.add(stylewrap);

             productStyleWrapperList.sort();
         }
    }
    /*public void createProductWrapper(){
        productLineWrapperList = new List<ProductLineWrapper>();
        for(gii__Product2Add__c prod: products){
            ProductLineWrapper prodWrapper = new ProductLineWrapper();
            prodWrapper.productStyle = prod.gii__ProductStyle__r.Name;
            prodWrapper.Name = prod.Name;
            prodWrapper.ProductCode = prod.gii__ProductCode__c;
            prodWrapper.forecast = ProductToForecastMap.get(prod.Id);
            prodWrapper.AvailableInInventory = ProductToAvailableMap.get(prod.Id);
            productLineWrapperList.add(prodWrapper);
        }
    }*/

    global class ProductStyleWarpper implements Comparable{
        public String productStyle{get;set;}
        public String productStyleId{get;set;}
        public List<ProductLineWrapper> productList{get;set;}

        // Compare opportunities based on the opportunity amount.
        global Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {

            // Cast argument to AccountHistoryWrapper
            ProductStyleWarpper CompareRec = (ProductStyleWarpper)compareTo;

            // The return value of 0 indicates that both elements are equal.
            Integer returnValue = 0;
            if (productStyle > CompareRec.productStyle) {
                // Set return value to a positive value.
                returnValue = 1;
            } else if (productStyle < CompareRec.productStyle) {
                // Set return value to a negative value.
                returnValue = -1;
            }

            return returnValue;     
        }
    }

    global class ProductLineWrapper implements Comparable {

         public gii__SalesOrderLine__c sol{get;set;}
         public String Id{get;set;}
         public String Name{get;set;}
         public String ProductCode{get;set;}
         public Decimal forecast{get;set;}
         public Decimal AvailableInInventory{get;set;}
         public Double OrderQuanity{get;set;}
         public Double unitPrice{get;set;}
         public Double unitAmountOff{get;set;}
         public Double discount{get;set;}
         public String pricingOverridenReason{get;set;}
         public String sellingUnitOfMeasure{get;set;}

         // Compare opportunities based on the opportunity amount.
        global Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {

            // Cast argument to AccountHistoryWrapper
            ProductLineWrapper CompareRec = (ProductLineWrapper)compareTo;

            // The return value of 0 indicates that both elements are equal.
            Integer returnValue = 0;
            if (Name > CompareRec.Name) {
                // Set return value to a positive value.
                returnValue = 1;
            } else if (Name < CompareRec.Name) {
                // Set return value to a negative value.
                returnValue = -1;
            }

            return returnValue;     
        }
    }

    public Boolean hasNext
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageNumber+1)<NoOfPages;
        }
        set;
    }

    public Boolean hasPrevious
    {
        get
        {
            return PageNumber>0;
        }
        set;
    }


    public void previous()
    {
        PageNumber--;
        getProducts();
    }

    public void next()
    {
        PageNumber++;
        getProducts();
    }


}
```

Comment: Could you also post the controller code?

Comment: i have added thecontroller code as well

Comment: One of your query is not returning any record. Can you put debug statements and see where you are getting the failure?